# laravel Array to string conversion error when adding a placeholder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my code

```
{{ Form::password('password') , array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'name' => 'pass') }}
```

This is the exception:

```
ErrorException
Array to string conversion
```

Could you help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array needs be the second argument of `Form::password()`, you closed the parenthesis too early. Blade thought you where thwowing an array in its `echo` structure: `<?php echo Form::password(), array('placeholder'...;?>` and therefore you got that 'Array to string conversion' error.

It should be:

```
{{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder' => 'Password', 'name' => 'pass')) }}
```

Definition:

> public string password(string $name, array $options = array())

Comment: Do you know any good page to understand who to add inputs, forms, textareas in laravel 4?

Comment: something easier. something directly telling me how to add inputs, radiobuttons and stuff like that

Comment: Docs are pretty easy...http://laravel.com/docs/html if you're stuck on something, please don't esitate to ask another question on that

Comment: Could you help me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286015/laravel-how-to-route-to-another-function-in-the-same-controller