# laravel how to route to another function in the same controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a controller for registering, when the user register successfully I would like to route him to his profile page.

In user controller I have these functions:

```
save
show($id)
```

when registering, the user fires the `save` function. so my question is how to route him to the `show` function with the id ?

I could make `view:make()` but I don't want to route him directly to the view but first I want to route him to the `show` function to do some stuff and then in the `show` function I do `view.make`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Redirect](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirect) functions

If you are using named routes:

```
return Redirect::route('profile', array($id));
```

If not:

```
return Redirect::to('user/show/' . $id);
```

Comment: the url becomes user/show/id but i got excpetion ` \ NotFoundHttpException` could u help ?

Comment: Can you access the url directly in the browser OK?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to route him to the `show()` method from the `save()` method, you can simply `return $this->show($id);` assuming you have his id.

You could even add extra variables to the view if you wish with `return $this->save($id)->with('some_data', $some_data);`

Comment: this will leave the url as `user/save/` though, which may be an issue

Comment: @user574632 yes exactly, I would prefer the url to become `user/show/id` not `user/save`